# How to setup M/monit agent behind a proxy?

Tags: proxy, agent, monit

I've been using mmonit for multiple different hosts to monitor various applications which are working perfectly fine and am very happy with how it is working.

However recently I've run into a wall trying to setup M/monit agent behind a proxy. Not the web interface, but the actual agent.

The host machine has limited connectivity with outside world and only via https proxy (source and destination addresses are limited).

I've tried to export https_proxy and/or http_proxy to no avail.

I've went trough available documentation however everywhere the proxy is mentioned is about setting up web interface behind a proxy and not the actual agent. Am I overlooking something simple? Or should I resort to usage of socat or other similar solutions?

Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>I faced the same problem and decided to use [`tsocks`](http://tsocks.sourceforge.net).</s>

EDIT: `tsocks` does not work because `monit` spawns child processes that are not wrapped by `tsocks`.

I ended up using [`socat`](https://packages.debian.org/de/sid/socat). Since my `m/monit` instance is behind SSL with a valid (not self-signed) certificate, I had to jump through one more hoop.

In `/etc/hosts`, I pointed my `m/monit` domain to `localhost`:

```
# /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1 mmonit.myserver.com
```

Then I started `socat` like this:

```
socat TCP4-LISTEN:9900,fork SOCKS4:socksproxy.our.corporate.network:123.45.67.89:443,socksport=1080
```

This does the following:

- Binds to TCP(4) port `9900`
- Allows multiple connections (`fork` option)
- Sends all requests through the SOCKS4 proxy `socksproxy.our.corporate.network`
- Forwards all requests to `123.45.67.89` on SSL port `443` (which is my `m/monit` host)

In `monitrc`, configure the `m/monit` host like this:

```
set mmonit https://monit:<yourpassword>@mmonit.myserver.com:9900/collector
```